# How to enter EOF in "line run" mode of bash terminal in emacs?

Tags: linux, bash, haskell, emacs

I am using bash terminal in emacs (mainly to run haskell interpreter).

Because the "line run" mode is easier (than "char run") for editing long commands, (as it supports most of the movement commands), I usually run scripts in line mode.

However, I sometimes enter infinite enumeration (such as printing out an infinite list) that keeps printing out numbers nonstoply. I am well aware of <kbd>C-d</kbd> for entering EOF to interrupt such infinite print-out, but it only works under char mode of terminal in emacs.

Question: 
How to enter EOF in **line run** mode of bash terminal in emacs?

Comment: If the script is printing something infinite, entering `EOF` won't have any effect in any mode -- `EOF` is only relevant when the program is waiting for input.

Comment: @Barmar 'EOF' works under "char run" mode even while the screen is printing infinitely.

Comment: `C-d` should work just fine in `term-line-mode` (as well as `term-char-mode`). Certainly it works for me. As mentioned, it's probably `C-c` you wanted, for which you'll need to use `C-c C-c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-c C-c` tells Emacs to send a signal to the shell equivalent to using `comint-interrupt-subjob`, which should stop the process from running.